# First time shown Activity solution

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I need to show one `SecondActivity` only once and only on first launch of the application. I implemented it like this (see below), but I don't really like a solution because I need to inflate layout on `onResume()` because if I do not I have an empty `Activity` when I click `back` hardware button being on `SecondActivity`.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public static final String FIRST_RUN = "FirstRun";

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(FIRST_RUN, false)) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Second.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

In `Second Activity` I just put flag `FirstRun` to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first `Activity` call `finish()` after you make the call to `startActivity(i)`

Like this...

```
if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(FIRST_RUN, false)) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
} else {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Second.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

You can then remove `setContentView(...)` from `onResume()`.

Answer (score 2):

The bestWay i can think is having Init activity that don't have any layout and just decides what activity to run first

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to prevent the user to go back to the activity, add the "noHistory" flag in your manifest file, like this:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity" android:noHistory="true">
```

If this is your "splash screen" activity, and only needs to be shown on app start, do this:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity" android:noHistory="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```